# Android next and previous buttons in Framelayout

Tags: android

I am trying to create a previous button to this framelayout so that it can have previous and next as well as home button.  Can anyone please help me? I just need help with adding the previous button.  Does anyone also know what would be the easiest way of adding numbers below the images, e.g. image 1 of 20 so that people know when they're at the last image.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int count = 1;
    FrameLayout frame;
    ImageView imageview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
    }
    public void btnClick(View view) {
        //---hide the current one---
        imageview = (ImageView) frame.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf(count));
        imageview.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);

    //---go to the next image---
        count++;
        if (count>3) count = 1;

    //---show the next image---
        imageview = (ImageView) frame.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf(count));
        imageview.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to go to the previous and next what? Activity? Image? Text on Screen?. Be more specific if possible.

Comment: Hi, I want to go to previous and next image for now.  Hopefully if I can do the images I will also be able to do the text views next.

Answer (score 0):

Set an `onClickListener` on your buttons:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // Change the images here
    }
});
```

Whenever you click your button the code inside `onClick` will be executed, so the only thing you do there is change the image. One listener for the next button and another for the previous.

Comment: I'm a a total newbie.  Can you make an example of what it would be.  What would it look like using your method for previous and next. The above code I used from an example.  I am still busy learning java to improve my skills and understand the concepts better.  Thank you in advance.